# CPU speed issue after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, cpu-speed

After upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 I see a performance issue related to the CPU.

As you can see from the screenshot, the actual CPU speed is shown as 1.18 GHz instead of the 2.27GHz that is shown in the CPU's description. Furthermore the system seems to use only one core. The laptop is a HP pavilion and about 6 years old.

Would you advise me to try changing the BIOS settings or to do anything else?

[image]
<sup>**Task Manager**</sup>

I also checked the power plan and found no issue.

Edit: even if the system is not responsive/high load the Cpu load does not go over 52%

Comment: Do you have any processor related options in the BIOS? Can you confirm your laptop model number, beyond HP Pavilion?

Comment: bios cpu virtualization did not make a differencr

Comment: Please confirm your laptop model?

Comment: the model is a hp pavilion dv 6

Comment: There are a hundred or more variations of the DV6, post the full product number please. [See this article on how to find it](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00033108)

Comment: One thing to check is Msconfig>Boot Tab>Advanced Options, there should be No boxes ticked.

Comment: product WA036EA#ABD

Comment: Are you sure whatever is using your CPU can even use more than two cores? Because that’s what’s up in your screenshot.

Comment: 2 physical cores logically 4 cores - sorry for the german screenshot

Comment: Yeah, so? The question still stands: Because right now, only two logical cores (or whatever you want to call them) are busy. Try with Prime95.

Answer (score 2):

recently I also upgraded from w7 to w10 my dell vostro 1710 and as many of you I had the same problem with cpu speed. 
Below you can find how it worked for me and I hope that will work also for you.
At first I tried to fix it directly from advanced power setting but didn't worked so:

1- reboot and enter to bios setup
2- Intel (R) SpeedSetup (TM) technology - change it to "Enabled"
3- exit saving changes

Now the cpu speed will go up to maximum speed depending on the load.
If you want that you cpu to have a stable max speed and not to be reduced to save some energy than follow the below steps.

1- Power option and select change plan settings
2- change advance power settings
3- click on "change settings that are currently unavailable"
4- Processor power management
5- Minimum processor state - set the desired value (max 100%)
6- check also the maximum processor state % if 100 than is ok

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see from the screenshot, the actual CPU speed is shown as 1.18 GHz
>   instead of the 2.27GHz that is shown in the CPU's description.

Yes, but that is the actual speed. Not the max speed.

The Descripton at the top shows what the CPU is build for. And you you max out the CPU for a longer period of time then both cores (and all 4 threads) will run at 2.26GHz.

But if you do not use the CPU power then it can either run 'bursty' at max speed, or it can slow down and still get the work done with less power used and less heat produced. This is a good thing.

If you prefer an analogy: Compare it to a car capable of going 226kmph (on a highway), but going only 50kmph down the street of a city. Rather then drive a few seconds as high speed, and then stop, drive again, stop again, ...  it simply drives at a slower speed.

[image: Task manager screenshot]

Basically, if there is more work to be done then the CPU speed will also increase. At least until it reaches 2.26GHz. For a short while it may even exceed that [turbo'ing up to 2.53Hz](http://ark.intel.com/products/43537/Intel-Core-i5-430M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_26-GHz), while producing more heat than it can shed.  All of this is normal behaviour.

> Would you advise me to try changing the BIOS settings or to do anything else?

No, it is working as designed. If it did not throttle down in windows 7 then I should actually consider fixing windows 7. (I guess this is one erea where windows 10 improved).

(If CPU speed stays at 1.18GHz, even when you run benchmarks or otherwise stress the system then please add this to the post because that changes everything).

Comment: I think the issue was a combo of patches and turning on virtualization on Bios level. now the machine runs as expected.

Comment: If you remember some more details then please feel free to post an answer to your own question. If might help future visitors.